# VS 2013 IDE, C# vs C/C++ folder structure

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer

In a Visual Studio 2013 C/C++ project, adding a folder in the Solution Explorer does not physically create a folder under my project path (on the hard disk). This way I can keep my project structure (in the solution explorer) separate from my folder structure (actual folders and files on the disk).

C# projects seem not to like this idea. In a C# project whenever I add a folder, the IDE tries to create it on the disk. Is there a way to stop this? Can I tell the IDE to use C/C++ behaviour?

Comment: In a C++ project you don't add a folder, you add a "filter".  Just a way to logically group source files.  A C# project actually creates a folder.  It was designed different because a C++ compiler generates .obj files that need to be stored somewhere, the C# compiler doesn't.  You can't make them behave the same way.

Comment: @HansPassant: So the project and the folder structures have to be co-dependent? I thought the Solution Explorer structure was just a view, I cannot imagine why it should represent a real structure on disk. Thanks for the reply.